# Jquery listening to triggered events?

Tags: jquery

I create an event in my infiniteScroll class by:

```
$.event.trigger('load');
```

Then I listen for it by:

```
this.infiniteScroll = new gd.InfiniteScroll();
this.infiniteScroll.on('load', this.loadData);
```

But this fails, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

Any idea where Im going wrong?

Comment: jQuery version issue?.. Which version are you using?

Comment: are you sure the script is loaded after jquery is loaded

Comment: Yes it's loaded after jquery.

Comment: Are you returning jQuery object from InfiniteScroll method?

Comment: Im not sure? Could you show me an example

Comment: Well, better would be you post relevant code...

Comment: I did, I posted it above.

Comment: I'm sorry but i cannot devine what is `gd.InfiniteScroll`

Comment: Just show me an example how to listen for a trigger. You dont need to see the class, it's not relevant.

Comment: You know, on() method is to bind event to jQuery object. So using on() method on non jQuery object throw an error, the one you see. So if you think your 'class' code is irrelevant, what can we do for you?!... BTW, "how to listen for a trigger." doesn't mean anything because a trigger fire the event, so to 'listen' to it, just bind the event...

Comment: So why didnt you just say bind the event in the first place?

Comment: @panthro because this is what you are already trying to do, using on() but on a non jQuery object... That's ok, we are turning here in circle with useless comments, GL